# How can I get touch input on Android Wear with OpenGL (Gles2WatchFaceService)?

Tags: opengl-es, wear-os

I am developing a watch face for Android Wear. In order to have smooth graphics, I switched from conventional canvas drawing to OpenGL (i. e., from CanvasWatchFaceService to Gles2WatchFaceService). For touch input, I was using

```
    @Override
    public void onTapCommand(int tapType, int x, int y, long eventTime) { ... }
```

That doesn't seem to work under Gles2WatchFaceService. How can I still get touch input?

Answer (score 1):

I found it. The style of the face watch needs to be set accordingly (setAcceptsTapEvents) in the onCreate function:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);

        setWatchFaceStyle(new WatchFaceStyle.Builder(CronosurfGLWatchFace.this)
                ...
                .setAcceptsTapEvents(true) // <== HERE!!
                ...
                .build());
        ...
    }
```

It is the same as for CanvasWatchFaceService. For some reason, I lost that style setting while I changed my code from canvas to OpenGL.